# How to install helm using homebrew?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to install helm package manager for Kubernetes and getting some errors. I'm using MacOS Mojave

I did `brew install kubernetes-helm` and I'm getting the below Errors:

```
Error: No available formula with the name "kubernetes-helm" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps
```

Anu suggestions on getting helm using `homebrew` succesfully?

Comment: What is the output of `brew doctor`? It looks like you have an entirely botched Brew installation and you'll be better off just reinstalling it

Answer (score 1):

Try a full url for the correct kubernetes-helm.rb file

```
brew unlink kubernetes-helm
brew install https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/kubernetes-helm.rb
```

Comment: `curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found`